# CollectionView Cell is not displaying in a Custom View component

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I tried to create a custom view component containing a label and a collectionView.

```
public final class RatingCollectionView: UIView {
// MARK: - Initialization

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    Bundle(for: classForCoder).loadNibNamed("RatingCollectionView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentVIew)
    contentVIew.frame = bounds
    contentVIew.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    initCollectionView()
}


public func initCollectionView() {
    starRatingCollectionView.dataSource = self
    starRatingCollectionView.delegate = self
    starRatingCollectionView.register(RatingStarCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "RatingStarCollectionViewCell")
}

@IBOutlet var contentVIew: UIView!
@IBOutlet private weak var starRatingCollectionView: UICollectionView!


extension RatingCollectionView: UICollectionViewDataSource {
public func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection _: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let ratingCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RatingStarCollectionViewCell

    ratingCell.configureRatingSelection()
    ratingCell.delegate = self
    return ratingCell
}
}


extension RatingCollectionView: UICollectionViewDelegate {
public func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt _: IndexPath) {
}
}


extension RatingCollectionView: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return starRatingCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
}

public func collectionView(_: UICollectionView,
                           layout _: UICollectionViewLayout,
                           sizeForItemAt _: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
}
```

When I called this view inside a ViewController,

```
@IBOutlet private weak var ratingView: RatingCollectionView!
```

the collection view cell is not displaying.Does anybody came across this issue(App is not crashing).?TIA

Comment: Are you using a xib guy?

Comment: collection view in xib file no works, you have create it programatically